# Impossible to set the rule "pointer-events" through JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've to manipulate the interaction with an element in runtime, making it invisible and "no interactible"..
The rule that can accomplish the second, is "pointer-events: none"

The problem is that it doesn't recognized from JS or jQuery... why?

Comment: Which browser do you need this work work on? `pointer-events` are not natively supported on any version of IE

Answer (score 21):

I don't think I understand the question, but (using jQuery)

```
$( document.body ).css( 'pointer-events', 'none' );
```

will work just fine for supporting browsers (ignoring any pointer event). However, if you *remove / hide* the element, pointer events will of course also no longer work if you hide it by

```
display: none
```

Comment: In jQuery i've used this syntax:
$("#scrittainfo").css({pointer-events:"0"})

and it didn't work.. instead using it for manimupale the "opacity", all works fine.. For what reason?

Comment: @AnnaLica `"0"` is no valid value for `pointer-events`. Set it to `none` instead.

Comment: It's the same thing, too using "none".. In the project i've regularly wrote "none", i've do a mistake to post it there

Comment: @Sonia `.css({pointer-events:"0"})` is not valid syntax because you can't have a `-` in a property without quoting it, like `.css({"pointer-events":"0"})`
But since you probably don't want to quote every property just to make it consistent with the ones that require quoting because of dashes, you can instead use [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)d  properties which jQuery considers equivalent: `.css({pointerEvents:"0"})`
Or you can use their alternate syntax which only uses strings: `.css("pointer-events", "0")`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the css `pointer-events: none;` to allow events to go through. Also, like 1j01 commented, jquery will accept camelCase to get around the problem of dashes in the name:

```
$('.my-class').css({pointerEvents: "none"})
```